# What is continuous quantum register and how it relates to qubits?

Tags: experimental-realization, computational-models, continuous-variable

I would like to understand what is a continuous quantum register.
I know the direct definition is a quantum register that stores a real number defined by an observable with a spectrum consisting of $\mathbb{R}$ but that seems really abstract to me.

Also how it relates to qubits? Is a set of qubits used for simulating discretely a continuous quantum register? If yes how?

Answer (score 2):

> direct definition is a quantum register that stores a real number defined by an observable with a spectrum consisting of ℝ

Yes, qubits can be used to discretize a continuous quantum system.

> How?

Lets say $\Phi $ is an operator on the continuous system which we want to simulate using qubits. We need a discrete register ($D$) to store the qubit values. Now the discretization is done by measuring the shifts between the eigenstates of $\Phi$ denoted by operator say $M$. This is done by DFT.
$$
M = F^*\Phi F
$$

Where $F$ is the DFT operator.

Now all this is considering that you already have a register which is storing continuous quantum output of a continuous system. "What is that register?" is I believe to be your original question. For that, you can take an example of cavity QED.

A typical quantum system with a continuous degree of freedom is the quantum field and normally, quantum simulations of quantum field theories rely on discretisation of this field.

Whereas **a cavity QED output is a continuous quantum field and *this* acts as a continuous quantum register.** [This](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d9ab/29b63427a7d1a3cc4714a89dfed8ee4356bf.pdf) thesis has even proposed an algorithm to be directly implemented on this continuous quantum field and only discretizing after the implementation, thus utilizing the underlying properties of continuous system.

Comment: Would it be possible to have a numerical example ? I am still lost about it. Like how is the real number encoded in this continuous register and what is the shift you mention?

Comment: So $\Phi$ is an operator on an infinite dimensional $\mathcal{H}$ and $F$ is the DFT on a $d^n$ dimensional Hilbert space. Then your composition doesn't make sense. Say your types.

Comment: @cnada and AHusain, I dont remember the complete mathematical proof of the descretization. I recollected that from my memory of reading a recent paper by a team at IQC. I will link that paper when I get home.